# Can jQuery .remove() be used without a click function?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have two classes removed (I do not have access to html document and will not have access to it in the forseeable future) so I'm thinking of using jQuery to do what I'm looking to do.

Now the reason I ask about the click function being required is because reading the jQuery documentation, I've only been able to replicate the same results with a click function.

The pre-built class (from our CMS) is written `<div class="entry-otpion-info-container">` and `<h3 class="menu-title">` The code I wrote to remove these classes is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("div").remove(".entry-option-info-container");
    $("h3").remove(".menu-title");

}
```

For some reason it didn't work.

Also, `.menu-title` is a nested element inside of the `div.entry-option-info-container`, it should be removed if the parent element is removed right? Unfortunately it didn't work with or without the h3 removal code.

I am using jquery v. 1.12, all my other jquery scripts work except this one. I added a JsFiddle to show that it doesn't work there either.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2k7drg4s/1/)

Any help is appreciated it! thank you for your time.

[Testpage](http://convio.cancer.ca/site/TR?fr_id=22046&pg=entry)

If you shrink down to mobile view, you'll see a big gap between "view more" and the Team graph, that won't disappear, the classes I'm trying to hide within "side-bar" class are part of the Team graphs you see, so its creating a large gap

Comment: `$("div .entry-option-info-container").remove();`

Comment: For removing a class from an element, use `.removeClass()`.

Comment: Also, your fiddle is broken.  Here is a fixed one: https://jsfiddle.net/yvatukuw/ (it was missing jQuery include and a closing right parenthesis).

Comment: thank you for the suggestions and @JosephMarikle thank you for fixing that. What's weird none of the suggestions are working. There is still this big whitespace-gap on my webpage in mobile view. i will edit question to include web page

Comment: I have edited the fiddle and it works for me. Please refer to the fork. https://jsfiddle.net/v3byuxgk/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").removeClass(".entry-option-info-container");
    $("h3").removeClass(".menu-title");
}
```

Comment: based off the suggestions I've given that a shot as well and I'm still getting the large whitespace gap, I edited my question to include more information